# Display the value of a seleted option before submission

Tags: php, forms

I want to echo the value(`$_POST[cat]`) of a selected option to show before I click submit that is if I select male it should echo or display male outside of the form tag below is a code:

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="" >
Gender:<br>
<select name="cat">
<option value="">select a gender</option>
<option value="male">male</option>
<option value="male">female</option>
</select>
</form>

<?php echo $_POST[cat]; ?>
```

Comment: Quite the trick -- showing the user `male` and `female` options, but both selections submit `male`.

Answer (score 0):

This can not be done with PHP. For that you have to use `JavaScript` or `jQuery`

Here is a `jQuery` [example](https://api.jquery.com/change/) of that.

Code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>change demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    color: red;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<select name="sweets" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Chocolate</option>
  <option selected="selected">Candy</option>
  <option>Taffy</option>
  <option selected="selected">Caramel</option>
  <option>Fudge</option>
  <option>Cookie</option>
</select>
<div></div>

<script>
$( "select" )
  .change(function () {
    var str = "";
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
      str += $( this ).text() + " ";
    });
    $( "div" ).text( str );
  })
  .change();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok can i put it in a varable like this <?php $value = '<div></div>'; ?> cos i when to use it in an if statement like this

if($value == "Chocolate"){
echo "good";
}else{
echo "bad";
}

Answer (score 0):

There you go

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="" >
Gender:<br>
<select name="cat" id="cat" onchange="checkCat();">
<option value="">select a gender</option>
<option value="male">male</option>
<option value="male">female</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="div1">

</div>

<script>
function checkCat() {
var oS = document.getElementById("cat");
var gender = oS.options[oS.selectedIndex].value;
var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode(gender);
para.appendChild(node);

var element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Ok can i put it in a varable like this <?php $value = '<div></div>'; ?> cos i when to use it in an if statement like this if($value == "Chocolate"){ echo "good"; }else{ echo "bad"; }

Comment: @simononi Don't really get your meaning. Is it you want to implement your php code into the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

As you've been told in the previous post, you can do it using jQuery or JS.
Here another example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    s = $('select[name="cat"]');
    
    $(s).change(function()
    {
        $("#gender-show span").html(s.val());    
    });
});
```

```css
*{padding:5px}
#gender-show span{font-weight:bold}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form name="form" method="post" action="" >
Gender:<br>
<select name="cat">
<option value="">select a gender</option>
<option value="male">male</option>
<option value="female">female</option>
</select>
</form>
    
<div id="gender-show">Gender Choice: <span></span></div>
```

Comment: Ok can i put it in a varable like this <?php $value ='<div id="gender-show">Gender Choice: <span></span></div>; ?> cos i when to use it in an if statement like this if($value == "male"){ echo "good"; }else{ echo "bad"; }

Comment: You can manage that value, in that way, only after a submit. If you don't want to submit the form you need to use javascript or jquery with their if..else costructor.